# Language library for app localization?

Tags: android, ios, localization

I am looking for some kind of language library for general keywords to add localization in my app (iOS/android). The library should contain at least the general keywords in major languages (like- next, cancel, ok, Enter your name, username, password etc.) And I will be more than happy to find out simple general instructions (i.e. Enter your username, You have entered wrong password, Please try again later, etc) in different languages as well. Is there any library for that?

What's the easiest and cost effective way to localize apps without hiring a translation company? How do you guys do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MyMemory to translate like this:

```
 http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=next&langpair=en%7Cfr
```

It returns JSON response with translation of "next" from English to French (`en-fr`).

MyMemory is 100% free. The only thing you have to do is to parse JSON and save it to `.string` localization file.

I just created a little tool for this question: https://github.com/shtefane/BSLocalizationTranslate.git

Comment: This link seems nice! It seems I need to call the api for each word separately, don't I?

Comment: Yes, and number of request is limited to 100per day or 1000 per day if you add email

Answer (score 0):

I hope you may be knowing that Google Play console has started to provide Translation service to developers in an easier and hassle free way. They have linked few third party translation companies to developer console. The developers can check the price per word from there and can contact them.

For details find the link below:

http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2013/11/app-translation-service-now-available.html

Comment: I didn't know that, I will check it. However, I was expecting more like open source library or database of regular keywords used in apps in different languages. Since there are a lot of common keywords used in thousands of apps, why should we pay for those common translated words? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see any creativity involved there.